# ignore column in minus statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am unable to find a solution to this problem.

There are two tables to minus from each other.

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC from tableA
minus
Select columnA, columnB, columnC from tableB
```

I need the data from tableA.columnC, however it will never match to tableB.columnC, so the minus statement will return both records.

Is there a way to ignore columnC from the minus statement but still return the results?

-Thanks

P.S. A little background on this problem.  I have a transaction table that list date of purchase, billed amount, item purchased (sometimes listed, sometimes not), account number of purchaser, and a unique identifier for the purchase.

This table holds both purchases and reversals. So if someone bought a item for 10.00 and then returns the item there is a -10.00 for that.  In some cases a person will buy, return, and buy that item again within the same day.  This data is from a third party.

Unfortunately a sum does not work in this case I need a line by line detail of all purchases that have not been reversed.

I was able to get the correct data by following this posts advice and using a:
[Prevent Oracle minus statement from removing duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859255/prevent-oracle-minus-statement-from-removing-duplicates)

However there is more information that I need from this table than just the information that I am using to minus off the returns.

This is why i would like help with the above statement.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

something on these lines should work:

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC from tableA a
where not exists
(Select 1 from tableB b where a.columnA=b.columnA and a.columnB=b.columnB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select cola,colb,colc from tableA as A
inner join
(select cola,colb from tableA
 minus
 select cola,colb from tableB) as B
 on a.cola = b.cola
 and a.colb = b.colb;
```

Comment: That should work but it is much wordier than using `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: The problem come in where there are five records for a single item within the same day, i.e. purchase, return, purchase, return, purchase.  If it on the first colA and colB in the minus statement then I will not get any of the records.  If i create a partition over statement the I will not be able to extract enough information.  I think that I can do this with a Stored procedure by looping through both the positive and negative records and identifying matching reversals.